# how to increase max ThreadPool Limit in asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net, iis, threadpool, asp-net-core-spa-services

How can I increase the **max thread pool limit** in ASP.NET Core, and which is the default value? Can you show an example?
I know in ASP.NET the default max threads limit is 5000, but what's the value in ASP.NET Core?
I got "thread-pool exhaustion" and need to increase it, because naturally the amount of user threads increases in the company.

Comment: Sounds like Microsoft does not want to change that for ASP.NET Core, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 1):

.Net Core 3.1 Console App ThreadPool Max Thread Information :
Result (Worker Threads: 32,767, Asynchronous I/O Threads: 1,000)

.Net Framework 4.8 Console App ThreadPool Max Thread Information :
Result (Worker Threads: 2,047, Asynchronous I/O Threads: 1,000)

Note: Used GetMaxThreads Method

Answer (score 0):

Recommended solution is to rewrite all your synchronous methods to asynchronous. You don't need more threads if you properly use async/await everywhere. The thread pool exhaustion is usually caused by synchronous methods which block threads for a long time. Those methods should be started with a parameter TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(action, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```